# Fancybox caption from the img tag not href

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Is there a way to have caption pulled from the `<img>` tag instead of `<a>` tag?

For example
Html:

```
<a rel="fancybox" href="#">
<img src="ball.jpg" title="this is the caption i want to show in fancybox" alt="alt text here" />
</a>

<a rel="fancybox" href="#">
<img src="ball2.jpg" title="this is the caption2" alt="alt text here" />
</a>

<a rel="fancybox" href="#">
<img src="ball3.jpg" title="this is the caption 3" alt="alt text here" />
</a>
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:
JQuery:

```
            $("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'titlePosition': 'inside',
                'titleFormat': function (title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    title = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
                    return '<span>' + title + '</span>';
                }
            });
```

Comment: what version of fancybox? because you are using options for v1.3.2+ and v2.x that are not compatible with each other.

Comment: jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fancybox v1.3.4 simply use the API option `titleFromAlt` where basically you set fancybox title on the `alt` attribute of the `img` tag (not the `title` attribute) like

```
<a rel="fancybox" href="#">
 <img src="ball.jpg"  alt="this is the caption i want to show in fancybox" />
</a>
```

then your script :

```
            $("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'titlePosition': 'inside',
                'titleFromAlt' :  true 
            });
```

you can learn more about [this option and how title works in fancybox v1.3.2+ here](https://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/3da14d88af2393cc/)

**#EDIT** : to force to read the `title` attribute from the `img` tag use the API option `onStart` like

```
        $("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'titlePosition': 'inside',
            'onStart' : function(currentArray,currentIndex){
               var obj = currentArray[ currentIndex ];
               this.title = $(obj).find('img').attr("title");
            }
        });
```

Comment: but for SEO purposes i need it to be pulled from "title" tag of the image.

Comment: see my edit for getting the `title` attribute from the `img` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("img[title=fancybox]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'titlePosition': 'inside',
            'titleFormat': function (title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                title = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
                return '<span>' + title + '</span>';
            }
        });
```

Comment: $("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({ HAS to be the caller for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```
      $("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn': 'elastic',
            'transitionOut': 'elastic',
            'titlePosition': 'inside',
            'titleFormat': function (title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                title = $(currentArray[currentIndex]).find('img').attr('title');
                return '<span>' + title + '</span>';
            }
        });
```

Or you can just pass parameter `'titleFromAlt' :  true`

Comment: @YograjGupta : are you fishing? you are copying the answers from other people's posts ... that is called plagiarism.

Comment: @JFK: I am not doing so, how can you say this?